# How can I query a view partial and render it in a modal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view partial in a strongly typed controller. Is it possible to render the would-be contents of that view partial on mouseclick?

### Example:

**Active View**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#fireModal" class="open-popup-link">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fireModal" class="open-popup-link">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fireModal" class="open-popup-link">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fireModal" class="open-popup-link">4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="modalView"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
          key: 'my-popup',
          type: 'inline',
          inline: {
            // Define markup. Class names should match key names.
            markup: '<div class="white-popup"><div class="mfp-close"></div>awesome</div>'
          }
        },
        {
            callbacks: {
                open: function(){

                }
            }
        });

        $('.open-popup-link').on('mfpOpen', function(e /*, params */) {
        var linkText = // how to I grab this? (e.g. 1, 2, 3, or 4)
        $.ajax({
            // call view partial withlinktext as parameter
            //on success
            //  var inlineContent = viewPartialContent
            // On error
            //  var inlineCOntent = 'Uh oh, something went wrong'
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**View Partial**

```
@model *******.Models.Reservation
<div class="container">
        <div class="section-heading">
            <h2 class="red">Confirm Your Reservation</h2><br />
        </div>
        <div class="section-content">
            <div class="row">
                <h3 class="black text-center">Are you sure you want to reserve space <span class="dark-red">@Model.SpaceNumber</span></h3>
                <h4 class="black text-center">for <span class="dark-red">@Model.Game.Description</span> on <span class="dark-red">@Model.Game.Date.ToShortDateString()</span>?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="hero-buttons text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-gray btn-lg white">No</a>
                    <form action="/api/Reservations" method="post" id="confirmationForm">
                        @Html.Hidden("eRaiderUserName", @Model.eRaiderUserName)
                        @Html.Hidden("SpaceNumber", @Model.SpaceNumber)
                        <input type="submit" value="Yes" class="btn btn-red btn-lg white">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Method for viewpartial in controller**

```
public ActionResult Confirm(int spaceNumber)
{
    var reservation = new Reservation { SpaceNumber=spaceNumber, UserName=AppSettings.CurrentUserName, Game=db.Games.FirstOrDefault(g => g.ID == AppSettings.CurrentGameID) };
    return View(reservation);
}
```

## Does this make sense, and can I make it work?

Comment: Your code looks too complicated for what you want to achieve. Where do you want to render the Partial View (that's what it's called, by the way)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things:

1. change your `Confirm` method, so that it returns `PartialView(reservation)` instead of `View(reservation)`
2. You need to use AJAX, for example jQuery ajax, to get the HTML, and render it in your page

   `$.ajax({url = 'the url for your Confirm action',
            type = 'GET', 
            dataType='html', 
            data = params}).done(function(html) {
       // use the jQuery and the html to inject it wherever you need in your page
   });`

NOTE: params is a jQuery object which contains the data you need to pass like spaceNumber in this case, i.e.

```
var params = { spaceNumber: 'spaceNumberValue' }
```